# How to find text coincidences in pandas dataframe column and counting it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
Text                       like=>apple        not=>here                  
i like apple                    0                 0
i do not like pears             0                 0
one two three                   0                 0
something here                  0                 0
something not here              0                 0
vla bla bla                     0                 0
```

And I need to fill the columns as:

```
Text                       like=>apple        not=>here                  
i like apple                    1                 0
i do not like pears             0                 0
one two three                   0                 0
something here                  0                 0
something not here              0                 1
vla bla bla                     0                 0
```

I do not know the the columns names except the Text column name, I need to take the column name and count the text coincidences in the data of the Text column.

the only idea that i have is take all the columns except the Text column in a list an iterate via iterrows row by row and column by column name and fill the data, but I suppose exist a better way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `iterrows`, you can achieve this vectorized per column.

```
In [41]: df.columns.to_series().drop('Text').values
Out[41]: array(['like=>apple', 'not=>here'], dtype=object)


In [42]: for ele in df.columns.to_series().drop('Text'):
    ...:     column_name = ele.replace('=>', ' ')
    ...:     df[ele] = df.Text.str.count(column_name)
    ...:     
    ...: 

In [43]: df
Out[43]: 
                  Text  like=>apple  not=>here
0         i like apple            1          0
1  i do not like pears            0          0
2        one two three            0          0
3       something here            0          0
4   something not here            0          1
5          vla bla bla            0          0
```